# [Airflow]: Running Python script with BashOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to Airflow and I am trying to apply DAG to run an ETL python script through BashOperator. Such ETL python scripts update pandas dataframe as new data emerges, and the output is an updated .csv file.

In the Airflow webserver UI, the tasks are successfully completed, however the .csv files are not being generated (it appears that the python scripts are not actually being executed by BashOperator).

Could you please help me to find out what is going on? Many thanks!

Below is my script and the Log message:

```
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime
 
with DAG('tester', start_date=datetime(2022, 9, 27),
schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *', catchup=False) as dag:
 
    task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        bash_command='echo python3 /G:/xxx/xxxxx/xx/xxxx/t3.py'
    )
    task2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='task2',
        bash_command='echo python3  /C:/airflow_docker/scripts/t1.py',
    )
    
    task3 = BashOperator(
        task_id = 'task3',
        bash_command='echo python3 /G:/xxx/xxxxx/xx/xxxx/t2.py'
    )
```

The Log message:

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=tester/run_id=manual__2022-09-28T10:15:38.095133+00:00/task_id=empresas/attempt=1.log
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1171} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: tester.empresas manual__2022-09-28T10:15:38.095133+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1171} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: tester.empresas manual__2022-09-28T10:15:38.095133+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1368} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1369} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1370} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1389} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): empresas> on 2022-09-28 10:15:38.095133+00:00
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 9879 to run task
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:79} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'tester', 'empresas', 'manual__2022-09-28T10:15:38.095133+00:00', '--job-id', '1381', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/another.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmptz45sf6g', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmp57jeddaf']
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:80} INFO - Job 1381: Subtask empresas
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {task_command.py:371} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: tester.empresas manual__2022-09-28T10:15:38.095133+00:00 [running]> on host 620a4d8bf7f5
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1583} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=tester
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=empresas
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-09-28T10:15:38.095133+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-09-28T10:15:38.095133+00:00
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {subprocess.py:62} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Running command: ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'echo /C:/***_docker/scripts/empresas.py']
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {subprocess.py:85} INFO - Output:
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - /C:/***_docker/scripts/empresas.py
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {subprocess.py:96} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1412} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=tester, task_id=empresas, execution_date=20220928T101538, start_date=20220928T101539, end_date=20220928T101539
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-09-28, 10:15:39 UTC] {local_task_job.py:279} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: Try to remove the `echo`

Comment: @EladKalif I did and I get this error:

[2022-09-29, 13:05:06 UTC] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - python3: can't open file'/C:/***_docker/scripts/empresas.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[2022-09-29, 13:05:06 UTC] {subprocess.py:96} INFO - Command exited with return code 2
[2022-09-29, 13:05:06 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1902} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 197, in execute
    f'Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code {result.exit_code}.'

Comment: So your issue was that echo just printed the path which is what you see in the log and why it finished with success. Your real issue is that this path is not reachable and this is what you need to address.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've used the production docker image to setup your Airflow environment. Docker doesn't have access to the absolute path you've specified. In fact, it creates a `/tmp` location while invoking the BashOperator (see the logs).

You have to specify your scripts location on your docker-file and make it available. Then you can invoke your scripts by specifying a path relative to the one mentioned in your docker-file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? I seem to be having the same issue, with no clue on how to proceed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131972/unable-to-run-a-simple-airflow-dag-with-bashoperator-calling-python-scripts. Thank you!