# Unable to run a simple Airflow DAG with BashOperator calling Python scripts

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, astronomer

I installed Airflow, both through Apache and Astronomer and wrote a really simple DAG with two tasks, each of which are BashOperators that call a Python script. The first Python script, in turn, reads a file and writes out a file, while the second one reads the file created by the previous Python script, reads another hardcoded file and puts them both in a local DB. Nothing too crazy. But with both versions of Airflow (Apache and Astronomer), I'm doing something wrong that just does not work. The DAG loads, looks okay in Airflow and runs "successfully", but does nothing at all. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Here's my code and what I tried:

The DAG:

```
import json
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain

from airflow.decorators import (
    dag,
    task,
)

PYTHON_SCRIPTS = "python_scripts"


@dag(
    schedule="@daily",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        "retries": 2,
    },
)
def parse_json_data():
    @task(
        templates_exts=[".py"],
    )
    def parse_json():
        BashOperator(
            task_id="parse_json_task",
            bash_command=f"python {PYTHON_SCRIPTS}/json_file_parser.py",
        )

    @task(
        templates_exts=[".py"],
    )
    def load_files():
        BashOperator(
            task_id="load_files_task",
            bash_command=f"python {PYTHON_SCRIPTS}/load_data.py",
        )

    parse_json_task = parse_json()
    load_files_task = load_files()

    chain(parse_json_task, load_files_task)


parse_json_data()
```

The two Python scripts:

json_file_parser.py

```
import gzip
import json

input_json_file = "../data_files/json_file.jsonl.gz"
parsed_json_file = "../data_files/parsed_json_file.json"

# Parse function to extract necessary data from nhtsa file 1
def parse_json_file():
    # Create an empty list to store the extracted data
    extracted_data = []

    # Open the zipped file using and loop through each line
    with gzip.open(input_json_file, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as jfile:
        
        # working code here


    # Write the extracted data to a new JSON file
    with open(parsed_json_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        json.dump(extracted_data, output_file, indent=4)


parse_json_file()
```

load_data.py

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


def load_processed_json_file(engine):
    try:
        nhtsa_df = pd.read_json("../data_files/parsed_json_file.json")
        nhtsa_df.to_sql(
            name="processed_json_data", con=engine, if_exists="replace", index=False
        )
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Parsed file not found.")


def load_lookup_file(engine):
    try:
        nhtsa_lookup_df = pd.read_csv("../data_files/data_lookup_file.csv")
        nhtsa_lookup_df.to_sql(
            name="lookup_data", con=engine, if_exists="replace", index=False
        )
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Lookup file not found.")


def main():
    db_url = "..."
    engine = create_engine(db_url)

    load_processed_nhtsa_file(engine)
    load_nhtsa_lookup_file(engine)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried a myriad of file locations and ways to get this to run, but it didn't work. When using Astronomer, I put the Python scripts in a folder called python_scripts under the include folder and then used a `template_searchpath`, after having tried to go the hardcoded route. However, neither approach worked. I put the data files in a folder of its own, also in the include folder, but it didn't work.

For Apache Airflow, I took a look at the example dags and it seemed to indicate that I could just create the Python script and data folders inside the example_dags folder and it would work, but it didn't.

To add to this mess, the DAG "runs successfully", but nothing actually happens. I've used Airflow several times in the past, but this is somehow beyond me. Any help would be great. Thank you!

**EDIT:** I followed the suggestion below, and it worked. Kinda. It now gives me an error:

```
can't open file '/private/var/folders/rh/wzc6ln9d67s3n259nvkxq57w0000gn/T/airflowtmpa1sasfg8/python_scripts/json_file_parser.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It seems like it's trying to look for the script, but can't find it. I tried setting the template_searchpath, giving it an absolute path etc., but nothing seems to work with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the operator wrong.

@task is another way to define PythonOperator, so what you are doing here its to define a PythonOperator that creates a BashOperator but never execute it..

You don't need it, you just need to assign the BashOperator as follow:

```
parse_json_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="parse_json_task",
        bash_command=f"python {PYTHON_SCRIPTS}/json_file_parser.py",
    )
load_files_task=BashOperator(
        task_id="load_files_task",
        bash_command=f"python {PYTHON_SCRIPTS}/load_data.py",
    )
```

Comment: Makes sense! And this kinda worked :) So thank you for that. However, I get this error (which is definite progress!) - `can't open file '/private/var/folders/rh/wzc6ln9d67s3n259nvkxq57w0000gn/T/airflowtmpa1sasfg8/python_scripts/json_file_parser.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. This is with Apache Airflow, where the DAG is in `example_dags` and these files are inside the `example_dags` directory itself. Do I need to add a `templated_searchpath`?

Comment: the example dag are located at : /home/airflow/.local/lib/python[VER]/site-packages/airflow/example_dags.

Answer (score 0):

I asked on Reddit too, and someone guided me there. Turns out, I need to set the `cwd` in the BashOperator and give it some context of where the script is actually located. Worked perfectly after that.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Airflow allows various ways for deployment and I'm not sure which way you're following. But looking at your error it seems to be running in some containerised environment.

Its better to use absolute paths in BashOperator if possible to solve these issues

```
parse_json_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="parse_json_task",
        bash_command=f"python /<airflow_home>/example_dags/python_scripts/json_file_parser.py",
    )
load_files_task=BashOperator(
        task_id="load_files_task",
        bash_command=f"python /<airflow_home>/example_dags/python_scripts/load_data.py",
    )
```

`airflow_home` being the configured Airflow home directory.